# How can a child class access its parent attributes without the "parent.attrib" syntax in Django?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, scope

I'm totally confused
in Django I can create a child class which is PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) with "admin.ModelAdmin" as its parent and assign a tuple to the "list_display"(tip: list_display is an attribute of admin.ModelAdmin class) inside the PostAdmin without writing "admin.ModelAdmin.list_display"...while in python to address a parent class's attribute one needs to use the "parent.attrib" syntax
and the fact is when I try admin.ModelAdmin.list_display it gives me errors!

here is the code in my "admin.py":

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from blog.models import post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      admin.ModelAdmin.list_display= ('title','publish', 'status')

admin.site.register(post,PostAdmin)
```

what am I missing?
I've searched a lot about python inheritance and couldn't understand the way the inheritance works in here...to be exact, **How the child class (PostAdmin) assigns the "('title','publish', 'status')" to its parent(ModelAdmin)?
how does it get there?**

here are some parts of admin.ModelAdmin codes(which is made by Django and located in options.py) that I found by going to ModelAdmin's definition

the first time **list_display** is used in options.py (where ModelAdmin is defined)

```
class BaseModelAdmin(metaclass=forms.MediaDefiningClass):
#...
def get_sortable_by(self, request):
        """Hook for specifying which fields can be sorted in the changelist."""
        return self.sortable_by if self.sortable_by is not None else self.get_list_display(request)
    """Encapsulate all admin options and functionality for a given model."""
#....
```

second encounter with **list_display**

```
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('__str__',)
    list_display_links = ()
    list_filter = ()
    list_select_related = False
    #.....etc
```

third encounter with **list_display**

```
def get_changelist_instance(self, request):
        """
        Return a `ChangeList` instance based on `request`. May raise
        `IncorrectLookupParameters`.
        """
        list_display = self.get_list_display(request)
        list_display_links = self.get_list_display_links(request, list_display)
        # Add the action checkboxes if any actions are available.
        if self.get_actions(request):
            list_display = ['action_checkbox', *list_display]
        sortable_by = self.get_sortable_by(request)
        ChangeList = self.get_changelist(request)
        return ChangeList(
            request,
            self.model,
            list_display,
            list_display_links,
            self.get_list_filter(request),
            self.date_hierarchy,
            self.get_search_fields(request),
            self.get_list_select_related(request),
            self.list_per_page,
            self.list_max_show_all,
            self.list_editable,
            self,
            sortable_by,
        )
```

fourth encounter

```
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        """
        Return a sequence containing the fields to be displayed on the
        changelist.
        """
        return self.list_display

    def get_list_display_links(self, request, list_display):
        """
        Return a sequence containing the fields to be displayed as links
        on the changelist. The list_display parameter is the list of fields
        returned by get_list_display().
        """
        if self.list_display_links or self.list_display_links is None or not list_display:
            return self.list_display_links
        else:
            # Use only the first item in list_display as link
            return list(list_display)[:1]
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, why are you trying to set an attribute on the base class? Why not just set the attribute `list_display` on the subclass?

Comment: Sorry but I'm setting the attribute on the subclass
I'm just asking how setting the attribute on subclass is possible while the list_display is not recognized as an attribute of the ModelAdmin parent class? I mean is there a way that I know the attribute list_display is inherited from the ModelAdmin parent class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way.

```py
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from blog.models import post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display= ('title','publish', 'status') ### Set the attribute on this class, not on the base class.
admin.site.register(post, PostAdmin)
```

Comment: Ok so I'm just asking how setting the attribute on subclass is possible while the list_display is not recognized as an inherited attribute from the ModelAdmin parent class? I mean is there a way that I know the attribute list_display is inherited from the ModelAdmin parent class? In c# using visual studio it would tell me if the attributes are inherited or not (as far as I remember) but in python using visual studio code it doesn't tell me anything... Is there a way to know what attributes are inherited from the parent class? (Using debugging mode or any other way that you suggest)

Comment: Do you want to find the parent's attributes? Use `print(dir(super()))`. `dir` gives you the list of all attributes of an object, and `super` gives you the parent class of the current class, so if you run the code inside the `PostAdmin` class, you'd get all the attributes of `ModelAdmin`. Out of the base class, you can use `print(dir(admin.ModelAdmin))` to print all the attributes of `ModelAdmin`.